# Display format string, int to percent

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, string-formatting

I have some integer values (between 1 and 100) and I want to use them in a progress bar, that has a DisplayFormatString property.

I also want to have the percent symbol '%' in the output string.

The problem is that by using the symbol, it automatically multiplies my value with 100, and it shows my values like 3300% when I wanted them 33%. How may I overcome this?

```
DisplayFormatString="0%"
```

Comment: Show your code and we will see.

Comment: The input is from an outer source. Also, I don't do the work in code, but in ASP.

Comment: What control are you using for the progress bar? Is it a DevExpress control?

Comment: @devdigital Yes, DevExpress ProgressBar.

Comment: Are you using DevExpress control?

Comment: Complete always your post with the correct tags!

Comment: Did you try with `0'%'` the percentage is in single quotes

Comment: @V4Vendetta Man, you rock! Simple solution, to a hidious problem. Please post your comment as an answer so I can vote it. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianMar Glad, so here it goes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `0'%'` as the `DisplayFormatString`, (percentage in single quotes) this should help in achieving to append the percentage sign to your number. So you get `33%`.

One more thing you could try maybe is `0\\%` (not sure if it would work or not) but should work out to the same `33%` as you desire.

Answer (score 4):

The `ProgressBar` assumes your input will be between 0 and 1. When you set the `DisplayFormatString` to `"P"`, this will be displayed as a percentage.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with your representation of percentage. Usually a percentage is a decimal 0 to 1 where 1 is 100% and 0 is 0%. So if you want to use the standard `string.Format` you'll have to divide your variable with 100.0 (so your int 33 becomes a decimal 0.33).
Something like this:

```
int progress = 33;
string.Format("{0:F}", progress / 100.0);
```

If you dont want to use that solution you could check out the [MSDN section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to find a format that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The standard .NET string formatting methods will multiply by 100 when formatting as percentages, as per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString).  Looks like you'll have to divide your input by 100 or change how it's calculated originally.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem while working with Data Annotations, I found it worked when I wrapped the 0 in curly brackets: `DataFormatString = "{0}%"`

Answer (score 0):

As show [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/Features/DisplayFormat.aspx): try to use `DisplayFormatString="P"`

Comment: You do not need to multiplies you value, the control do it for you.

Comment: Both p and P work to display a percentage. One displays as is whilst the other performs the multiplier (cant remember which way round now)