# How to show Percentage (%) sigh in side text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show percentage (%) symbol in side text box by using DisplayFormat attribute with Property.

I am using MVC3

> **My Model is**

```
public class CommodityParticularInfo : EntityBase
{
    private decimal? _standardReceived;
    public decimal? StandardReceived
    {
        get { return _standardReceived; }
        set { _standardReceived = value; }
    }
}
```

> **View Is**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StandardReceived, new { @class = "textboxreadonly", @style = "width:100%", @ReadOnly = "ReadOnly" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 0'%' as the DisplayFormatString, (percentage in single quotes) this should help in achieving to append the percentage sign to your number. So you get 33%.

One more thing you could try maybe is 0\% (not sure if it would work or not) but should work out to the same 33% as you desire.

[Display format string, int to percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391851/display-format-string-int-to-percent)

Comment: This is a direct copy and paste from your linked question. Might have been better to just link the answer.. giving full credit to the author.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thats why i put the link there

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]     
 public decimal? StandardReceived
 {
       get { return _standardReceived; }
       set { _standardReceived = value; }
 }
```